# Set latitude & longitude directly in THREE.OrbitControls()

Tags: three.js

I made some code to convert from a latitude and longitude to an XYZ point on a sphere. Now I want to do the opposite - I am using `THREE.OrbitControls()` and want to set the location of the camera it is controlling given a latitude and longitude. I don't see a way to do it directly but perhaps there are some small changes I can make to the `OrbitControls()` code to allow me to do it?

Perhaps there is a better way with a different control but I have not found one.

Molly

Comment: Something like this: `controls.object.position.setFromSphericalCoords( radius, phi, theta ); controls.update();` See the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords

Comment: The comment above should work, you should just be aware that theta is the colatitude, thus far I guess you have something like  latitude = Math.PI/2-theta if I'm not mistakening.

Comment: Thank you both - I'm getting in a muddle converting my latitude and longitude to phi and theta - seems to work and then fails for one of the 4 +/- quadrants.  What is the right way to convert a standard lat/long I might take from an atlas to theta/phi?